# select одну следующую значение

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть таблица ***staffs***

```
STAFF_ID      DEP_ID
   1            55
   2            55
   3            55
   4            55
   5            55
   6            55
   7            55
   8            55
   9            55
  10            55
```

мне нужен написать такой `select staff_id from staffs where dep_id = 55`, но каждий раз получить одну следующую значению
например

```
.
```

первий раз `staff_id = 1,`
второй раз `staff_id = 2`

```
.
.
.
```

десятий раз `staff_id = 10` 
и после етого цикл опят повтарилься

Comment: язык программирования?

Comment: А чем разделены эти "разы", почему бы не прочитать из курсора в обычном цикле. Если единый курсор не подходит, поясните почему именно не подходит. надо же где то будет запоминать какую запись последний раз читали. А это либо переменная пакета, если все в переделаз одного соединения, либо отдельная таблица для фиксации этого и работа с ней функцией в автономной транзакции

Comment: Надо объявить курсор и написать два цикла - так я перевёл.

Comment: и как мне написать? если не сложно помочьте